# apache webserver adaptive video streaming

Tags: apache, video, web, webserver, video-streaming

While looking for video streaming server with Adaptive Bit Rate using http, I came across some proprietary servers/implementation namely Adobe dynamic streaming for Flash, Apple HTTP adaptive streaming and a similar one from microsoft.

What I am looking for is Apache webserver ABR streaming, I found out that MPEG DASH is the standard for this, and looks like apache supports it. But I am not able to get a start to it.

Can someone point me to an example or steps to achieve this?

Also, I understand that such a streaming requires a bunch of video files acting as segments at different bit rates of a video file that needs to be streamed and some metadata file.
I am not able to understand how I can provide this to apache to make it stream to the client(browser).
Appreciate help or directions on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using MPEG-DASH, streaming becomes very simple. The video is stored at different quality levels (in terms of bitrate, resolution, etc.) on any HTTP server, each divided in segments of a few seconds length. The (intelligent) client application requests the segment for a specific time and quality (dependent on the current network capacity) via standard HTTP GET requests. So you can use your "standard" apache or any other webserver.

To get started I suggest to get some DASH content, either from [DASHIF](http://dashif.org/testvectors/), or generate content on your own the easy way, using a transcoding platforms, like [bitcodin](http://www.bitcodin.com/).